# Inconsistent gcc behaviour for __attribute((const))

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, function-attributes

I've come accross a very strange behavior in gcc regarding operators and functions marked with `__attribute((const))`. Logical and arithmetic operators lead to different optimizations, and I don't understand why.

It's not really a bug since `__attribute((const))` is only a hint and there's no guarantee to its effect, but still this is very surprising. Anyone has any explanation ?

Here's the code. So I define an `__attribute((const))` function:

```
int f(int & counter) __attribute((const));
int f(int & counter) {
    ++counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I define an operator testing macro. This is done with macros and not templates/functors to present simple code to the compiler and simplify the optimization:

```
int global = 0; // forces results to be computed

#define TestOp(OP) \
    { \
        int n = 0; \
        global += (f(n) OP f(n)); \
        std::cout << "op" #OP " calls f " << n << " times" << std::endl; \
    }
```

And finally, I test different operators as follows. The comments match the output with `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic` same output at `-O3` and `-Ofast`

```
int main() {
    // all calls optimized away
    TestOp(^)   // 0
    TestOp(-)   // 0
    // one call is optimized away
    TestOp(|)   // 1
    TestOp(&)   // 1
    TestOp(||)  // 1
    TestOp(&&)  // 1
    // no optimization
    TestOp(+)   // 2
    TestOp(*)   // 2

    return global;
}
```

My question is: why do arithmetic operators yield two calls? Why couldn't `f()+f()` be optimized as `2*f()` ? Is there a way to help/force this optimization ?
At first I thought multiplication might be more expensive, but I tried with `f()+....+f()` and 10 additions still don't reduce to `10*f()`. Also, since it's `int` arithmetic, operation order is irrelevant (contrary to `float`s).

I also checked the asm but it doesn't help: all ints seem to be pre-computed at compile-time.

Comment: you sould maybe try it with O3

Comment: @PlasmaHH: doesn't change

Comment: The docs warns that a const function must not inspect pointer arguments, i'd presume that would be the same for references (and let alone also change any of the arguments passed in - const is supposed to be even stricter than the pure attribute).

Comment: @nos Well, obviously there's no "legal" means to debug a const function, so I'm stuck with this. But that souldn't be an issue since these attributes are not checked and the compiler is supposed to trust me about it.

Comment: what happens when you remove the __attribute((const)) from the function , or when you put the function inside a class member where you can put `const` directly?

Comment: @Antonie Well, if you make your function `int f(int i) __attribute((const));` , place the implementation in a different compilation unit (where it alters a global variable to keep track of the count), I get quite different results - only TestOp(|) performs 1 call, the others are optimized away, which would be the expected case when calling f(0).

Comment: As mentioned by `nos` the issue might be that the function call is inlined before being elided.

Comment: @nos Indeed, putting it in another compilation unit changes results!

Comment: Well, the code is UB, so anything the compiler does is legitimate. `f(n)` modifies its argument, so `f(n) OP f(n)` modifies the same value twice without a sequence point in between. It's like writing `++n+++n` or something similar.

Comment: @Damon It's a function call, so there will be a sequence point, there's no such issue. You can't be certain which of the left hand or right hand side is called first though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't trust you. 
Since you have a reference argument, the compiler doesn't seem to trust your `const` attribute - a `const` function is supposed to only look at values passed through the arguments (not references or dereferencing pointers).

Another way to test this is to break the `const` function out in a separate compilation unit:

test1.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int global = 0; // forces results to be computed

int f(int i) __attribute((const));
void print_count(void);

#define TestOp(OP) \
    { \
        int n = 0; \
        global += (f(n) OP f(n)); \
        printf("op %s ", #OP);\
        print_count();\
    }

int main() {
    // all calls optimized away
    TestOp(^)   // 0
    TestOp(-)   // 0
    // one call is optimized away
    TestOp(|)   // 1
    TestOp(&)   // 1
    TestOp(||)  // 1
    TestOp(&&)  // 1
    // no optimization
    TestOp(+)   // 2
    TestOp(*)   // 2

    return global;
}
```

counter.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int counter = 0;

int f(int i) {
    ++counter;
    return 0;
}

void print_count(void)
{
   printf("counter %d\n", counter);
    counter = 0;
}
```

Now the compiler figures out that there's no need to call `f(0)` until `f(0) | f(0)`, and the result of that one call to `f(0)` is re-used for the other cases.

```
$ g++ -O2 -c counter.cpp && g++ -O2 -c test.cpp && g++ counter.o test.o && ./a.out
op ^ counter 0
op - counter 0
op | counter 1
op & counter 0
op || counter 0
op && counter 0
op + counter 0
op * counter 0
```

Comment: Thanks! So the compiler only "trusts" me if it's in another compilation unit ? When it's in the same unit, wouldn't it make sense to issue a warning when the compiler removed my attribute annotation ?

Comment: But what's the deal with `f(0) | f(0)`? I don't see why it should be any different

Comment: @harold I changed it, it's not special - it's just the first time the compiler needs to call f(0). To be able to test all operators seperatly, you'd have to call f(n) with a different n for each operator though.

Comment: I think it is good in this case that the compiler doesn't trust him. To expand on the explanation, the reason it works in a separate compilation unit is that at the call site, the compiler can't see the contents (since it is in another compilation unit), so it is more willing to believe the annotation, since it has no reason not to.